# vtk6.1 shaders in/attribute variable

Tags: c++, glsl, vtk

I have a `vtkPolyData` filled with points and cells that I want to draw on the screen. My polydata represents [brain fibers](https://www.google.ca/search?q=brain+fibers&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=x_yEU-WwA-_msAT82YHQBQ&ved=0CF8QsAQ&biw=1312&bih=921#q=brain+fibers&tbm=isch) (list of lines in 3D). A cell is a fiber. It's working, but I need to add colors between all points. We decided to color the polydata using a shader because there will be a lot of coloring methods. My vertex shader is:

```
vtkShader2 *shader = vtkShader2::New();
shader->SetType(VTK_SHADER_TYPE_VERTEX);
shader->SetSourceCode(R"VertexShader(
    #version 120
    attribute vec3 next_point;
    varying vec3 vColor; // Pass to fragment shader

    void main() {
        float r = gl_Vertex.x - next_point.x;
        float g = gl_Vertex.y - next_point.y;
        float b = gl_Vertex.z - next_point.z;

        if (r < 0.0) { r *= -1.0; }
        if (g < 0.0) { g *= -1.0; }
        if (b < 0.0) { b *= -1.0; }

        const float norm = 1.0 / sqrt(r*r + g*g + b*b);
        vColor = vec3(r * norm, g * norm, b * norm);

        gl_Position = ftransform();
    }
)VertexShader");
shader->SetContext(shader_program->GetContext());
shader_program->GetShaders()->AddItem(shader);
```

The goal here is, for each point, get the next point to calculate the color of the line between them. The problem is that I can't find a way to set the value of "next_point". I'm pretty sure it's always filled with 0.0 because the [output image is red, blue and green on the sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTRh9.jpg).

I tried using vtkProperty::AddShaderVariable() but I never saw any change and the method's documentation hints about a "uniform variable" so it's probably not the right way.

```
// Splitted in 3 because I'm not sure how to pass a vtkPoints object to AddShaderVariable
fibersActor->GetProperty()->AddShaderVariable("next_x", nb_points, next_x); 
fibersActor->GetProperty()->AddShaderVariable("next_y", nb_points, next_y);
fibersActor->GetProperty()->AddShaderVariable("next_z", nb_points, next_z);
```

I also tried using a `vtkFloatArray` filled with my points, then setting it as a data array.

```
vtkFloatArray *next_point = vtkFloatArray::New();
next_point->SetName("next_point");
next_point->SetNumberOfComponents(3);
next_point->Resize(nb_points);
// Fill next_point ...
polydata->GetPointData()->AddArray(next_point);
// Tried the vtkAssignAttribute class. Did nothing.
```

**tl;dr** Can you please tell me how to pass a list of points into a GLSL attribute variable? Thanks for your time.